# XAML DataTemplate of View ViewModel how to refer to it when using an attached behavior?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF app with one window that has a ViewModel that hosts several user controls (with their own viewmodels) inside that `MainWindow`, in a `ContentControl`. I set up the view models for all my user controls in the view model of my main window, like so:

```
// Add Client Billing pages
ActiveContributorsVM = new ActiveContributorsVM();
PageViewModels.Add(ActiveContributorsVM);
```

So, in the XAML of my main window, I have:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!--Client Billing User Controls and View Models-->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ClientViewModels:ActiveContributorsVM}">
        <ClientViews:ActiveContributors />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Where `ActiveContributorsVM` is my `ViewModel` and `ActiveContributors` is my View for the user control that i am hosting in the content control.  This works fine and displays everything perfect.  Then i tried to add a behavior to the xaml of the ActiveContributors user control's XamDataGrid as below:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid Name="ActiveDP" Grid.Row="3" Theme="RoyaleStrong" ActiveDataItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" BindToSampleData="False" DataSource="{Binding ActiveContrib}" AutoFit="True" >
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <b:XamDataGridSelectedItemsBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

This results in a null exception in the behavior's class, specifically the `SelectedItems` collection.  I'm assuming it is using a different instance of my `ActiveContributorsVM` view model.  How would i refer to that Vview model, which has already been created?  I know the behavior class works fine when the datacontext is set as in the example I got it from:  http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/80298.aspx

Comment: I am having the same issue. Were you able to sort it out?